# Telerik RadGrid conditional display

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

This is my RadGrid code in asp.net page

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvData" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px"
        Width="1000px" Height="300px" CellSpacing="0"
        OnItemCommand="grvData_ItemCommand"
        OnNeedDataSource="grvData_NeedDataSource" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"  Skin="skn_RadGridCustom"
        SkinsDir="|CurrentTheme|/" SkinsPath="|CurrentTheme|/" >
        <ClientSettings>
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView PageSize="10" 
            AllowFilteringByColumn="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowSorting="True">

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" DataType="System.Int64" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="Id" Display="true">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DetailId" DataType="System.Int64" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="DetailId" Display="true">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Reject column" UniqueName="Reject" HeaderText="Reject" Display="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnReject" runat="server" ButtonType="StandardButton" Text="Reject" CommandName="Reject" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

How can I display Reject button with enabled/disabled mode based on column IsCancelled=1/0 from the stored procedure that is Databound to the RadGrid while loading the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX.CS** Please subscribe the "ItemDataBound"  event for your radgrid.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
                GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                RadButton btnReject = item.FindControl("btnReject") as RadButton; 

                if (item.GetDataKeyValue("IsCancelled").ToString() == "1")
                {
                    btnReject.Enabled = true;
                }
        else
        {
                    btnReject.Enabled = false;  
        }

    }
}
```

**ASPX**
To access the 'IsCancelled' field into C# code please assign this field as datakey.

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id,IsCancelled">
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: I already have a DataKeyNames as "Id". How can I have "Id" and "IsCancelled" both under DataKeyNames